# In a live environment in mongoDB, how can I ensure the ability to 'undo' an update operation?

Tags: mongodb, rollback

I can't share specifics due to work policy, but basically in my collection some but not all records have an element 'wannaRemove' in an array. Functionally the element exists on random records - once it's removed there's no way to determine which records had it without a rollback or some prior planning. I'm inexperienced with Mongo outside of the very basics.

I need to have a rollback plan so that we can monitor the system for a period after making the change and, if there are any errors, undo the change.

The environment will be live as we do this, so records could be modified after I remove the field but before we decide to undo it... So I can't just roll back to a dump taken just before the change. There are a very large number of records, so undoing manually isn't feasible.
The script I have to actually make the change is as follows:

```
db.myCollection.updateMany({"myArray.wannaRemove":{$exists:true}},{$unset:{"myArray.$[].wannaRemove":1}},false,true)
```

How can I ensure the ability to undo this change after a monitoring period?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the oplog to see what changed recently?

Comment: Ex: Consider copying property `wannaRemove` value to `cloneWannaRemove` and remove property `wannaRemove`, if it is required to undo then create your previous property from the cloned property otherwise remove the cloned property only.

Comment: Perhaps instead of trying to maintain the ability to rollback the change, you instead 'soft delete' it by no longer surfacing/returning that field. You could accomplish this in a variety of ways including introducing a view that is read from instead of the collection itself. With this approach there is no data modification needed if it has to be rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few possible approaches you can take with various levels of complextion and overhead, depending on how delicate this is, how much confidence you have in your code and so on.

I would personally suggest using one of the two following options, rated by personal pereference.

1. Do a logical delete, I personally rather do logical deletes whenever possible - This is my personal favorite approach in general.
   It allows you to revert/track any deletion while your application can handle the logic of such items.

For example you can just set a deletion field with timestamp that u can query afterwards:

```
  db.myCollection.updateMany(
    { 'myArray.wannaRemove': { $exists: true } },
    {
      $set: { 'myArray.$[].removedAt': new Date() },
      $unset: { 'myArray.$[].wannaRemove': 1 },
    },
    false, true);
```

Obviously this will only keep track of the "latest" deletion, you can maintain an array of dates instead if multiple deletions can occur.

2. Use a change stream and create a dump of the relevant actions, Using the change stream you can "listen" to this collection, whenever this specific event occurs you can dump it to a separate collection. this will give a very clear "history" of all events and will also allow you to restore previous states if needed.